# issues with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to install and run Spree on my local machine by following the steps mentioned in Getting started with Spree - http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html

However, when I start the server I get the following error (main page)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ProductsController#index

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products.individual_sale' in 'where clause': SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (products.deleted_at is NULL) AND (products.individual_sale = 1) AND (products.available_on <= '2011-04-01 14:50:07')
Can someone please help me out with this?

Installed with sample data, empty shop works ok.

Rails 3.0.5 ruby 1.8.7

Comment: This can't be happening, your sentences are identical to this fellow's! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840250/issues-with-spree did you copy paste it? or is that you Emmet Brown? Great Scott!

Answer (score 4):

Run the following:

rails g spree_product_assembly:install

rake db:migrate

http://groups.google.com/group/spree-user/browse_thread/thread/d8e70e68144da664/23df08505df7b3d2?lnk=gst&q=products+individual_sale#23df08505df7b3d2